# How i can use bluetooth received string in if() statement?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to use received string from bluetooth in my android application but i am unable to use it with if statement, actually i want to compare received string with my operations so that user send string and android app do some task according to it as i will add in it, so please tell me how i can do that, Thanks , please help me :(

```
  public static final UUID SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("34B1CF4D-1069-4AD6-89B6-E161D79BE4D9");
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
private static BluetoothService instance = new BluetoothService();
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private Handler mHandler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

private BluetoothService() {
    mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d(TAG, "got a notification in " + Thread.currentThread());
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public static BluetoothService getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    //close existing connections
    if (mConnectedThread != null) mConnectedThread.cancel();
    if (mConnectThread != null) mConnectThread.cancel();

    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
}

private void manageMyConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket mmSocket) {
    if (mmSocket.isConnected()) {
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }
}

public boolean send(String command) {
    return mConnectedThread.write(command);
}

public void registerNewHandlerCallback(Handler.Callback callback) {
    mHandler = new Handler(callback );
}

// Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
// service and the UI.
public interface MessageConstants {
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket
        // because mmSocket is final.
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        try {
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice.
            // SERVICE_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used in the server code.
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERVICE_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "creatE() error  socket", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", closeException);
            }
            return;
        }

        // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
        // the connection in a separate thread.
        manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
        // member streams are final.
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
        }
        try {
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream.
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                int read = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                if (read < 4) {
                    this.cancel();
                }
                int dataLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).getInt();

                buffer = new byte[dataLength];
                read = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                if (read < dataLength) {
                    this.cancel();
                }


                String command = new String(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, -1, -1, command);

                readMsg.sendToTarget();
                Log.d(TAG, "reading values");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
    public boolean write(String command) {
        try {
            // Allocate bytes for integer indicating size and message itself
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + command.length())
                    .putInt(command.length())
                    .put(command.getBytes());

            mmOutStream.write(bb.array());
            mmOutStream.flush();

            // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
            Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, command);
            writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

            // Send a failure message back to the activity.
            Message writeErrorMsg =
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("toast",
                    "Couldn't send data to the other device");
            writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
    bs.registerNewHandlerCallback(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                String toasttext = "";
                String a = "";
           //     Log.d(TAG, "got a notification in " + Thread.currentThread());

                if (msg.what == BluetoothService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ ){

                    toasttext = "";

                    //here i want to use received string in if statement , .....

                }

                else if (msg.what == BluetoothService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST) {

                    toasttext = "Info: ";
                }
                else if (msg.what == BluetoothService.MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE) {

                    toasttext = "Sending to device: ";
                }

                toasttext += msg.obj.toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toasttext, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG,null, t);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare to strings, you need to use equals().

```
String str1 = "myString1";
String str2 = "myString2";
String str3 = "myString1";

if(str1.Equals(str2)) {
    // Will not execute
    doSomething();
} else if(str1.equals(str3)) {
    // Will execute because str1 is the same as str3
    doOtherThing();
}
```

doOtherThing() will be run. You can use this model where you store the bluetooth string in str1 and then compare it to whatever strings you want.

Comment: i know about that , but bluetooth received string is not storing in any string variable. that is my problem,